# Scraping across many pages in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape a patent dataset from https://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/index.php/paten?type=2&q8=1993&q27=ID&skip=0. I want to collect the following information: application number, status, and title. I have been able to scrape the first page. However, I need to save all 6 pages. Any idea how to do this in R in the simplest way?
Below are my codes:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/index.php/paten?type=2&q8=1993&q27=ID&skip=0'
webpage <- read_html(url)
no_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.number')
no_data <- html_text(no_html)
status_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.approved')
status_data <- html_text(status_html)
title_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.title')
title_data <- html_text(title_html)
DF1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(no_data,status_data, title_data))
write.csv(DF1,"ptn.csv")
```

Thanks a lot beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Appears each page is only 10 entries. You can change `url` such that at the end it says `...=ID&skip=10` to get to the second page. The third page would be with `skip=20` and so on.

Here's one way of doing this:

```
# this is the url we keep modifying
base_url <- 'https://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/index.php/paten?type=2&q8=1993&q27=ID&skip='

# get list of all urls we need to access
urls <- sapply(seq(from = 0, by = 10, length.out = 6), function(z) return(paste(base_url,z,sep = "")))

library(rvest)

# Using your current code
readUrl <- function(url){
  webpage <- read_html(url)
  no_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.number')
  no_data <- html_text(no_html)
  status_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.approved')
  status_data <- html_text(status_html)
  title_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.title')
  title_data <- html_text(title_html)
  DF1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(no_data,status_data, title_data))
  return(DF1)
}

output_list <- lapply(urls, readUrl)
```

I do think there is something amiss with the the html tags etc. in your code because `no_data`, `status_data` and `title_data` are not of the same length leading to recycling of the shorter vectors.

```
> x <- readUrl(urls[1])
Warning message:
In cbind(no_data, status_data, title_data) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
> str(x)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ no_data    : Factor w/ 10 levels "P00199305441",..: 10 1 2 3 5 6 8 9 4 7 ...
 $ status_data: Factor w/ 5 levels "Berakhir","Dalam Proses",..: 4 1 4 4 4 4 5 2 5 5 ...
 $ title_data : Factor w/ 13 levels "ADISI YODIUM PADA PEANUT OIL TANPA MELALUI ESTERIFIKASI",..: 8 2 5 9 6 7 12 11 10 1 ...
```

for `urls[1]` (which is the one in the OP), the lengths of `no_data`, `status_data` and `title_data` are 10, 11 and 13 respectively.

Comment: Hi Gautam, thanks a lot for your response. I have solved the warning status by changing my data frame command to the following:DF1 <- rbind(DF1, cbind(no_data,status_data, title_data)). However, my output just a repetition from page one, such as P00199305441
P00199305441
P00199305910
P00199305910
P00199307353
P00199307353

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help. I have just solved my problem using Python using the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
file = "paten.csv"
f = open(file, "w")
Headers = "Nomor, Status, Judul\n"
f.write(Headers)
for skip in range(0, 20, 10):
    url = "https://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/index.php/paten?type=2&q8=1993&q27=ID&skip={}".format(skip)
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    Title = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"content"})
    for i in Title:
        try:
            Nomor = i.find("span", {"class":"number"}).get_text()
            Status = i.find("span", {"class":"approved"}).get_text()
            Judul = i.find('a', {"class":"title"}).get_text()
            print(Nomor, Status, Judul)
            f.write("{}".format(Nomor).replace(",","|")+ ",{}".format(Status).replace(",", " ")+ ",{}".format(Judul).replace(",", " ")+ "\n")
        except: AttributeError
f.close()
```